# Unable to Get Connection From Connection Class

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, database-connection

I am new to `Java` and developing a `Swing` application, so this project is all depending on `JDBC`, its very big project for me, i am trying to create a single `Connection` `Class` and use it in my entire project.

i have written a code to get `connecton`

```
package sab;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionManager {

private static String url = "jdbc:h2:~/test";    
private static String driverName = "org.h2.Driver";   
private static String username = "sa";   
private static String password = "";
private static Connection connection;
private static String urlstring;

public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // log an exception. fro example:
            System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection."); 
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // log an exception. for example:
        System.out.println("Driver not found."); 
    }
    return connection;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    getConnection();
}
```

}

but when ever i am trying to test connection it show

```
Failed to create the database connection.
Driver not found.
```

i dont Know what am doing wrong someone please help

Comment: Show us the stack-trace of your `SQLException` `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: If you include `ex.printStackTrace()` in your catch blocks it should tell you exactly why the connection is failing. Examining the stack trace is very important when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friends i have created the connection good,thanks @Mihir and @Rocky that helped, its actually `ClassNotFoundException`, forgot to add Jar file to my project. my mistake!